# change the param value in $resource

Tags: angularjs, rest, resources, angular-resource, ngresource

I want to build an resource with this kind of URL :

/api/v1/users?userType=PREMIUM&param2=value2

## I have resource with the following configuration :

```
return $resource("/api/v1/users?userType=PREMIUM&param2=value2, {},
        {   'get'   : {method:'GET'   },
            'save'  : {method:'POST'  },
            'query' : {method:'GET'   },
            'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
            'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
        });
```

I want to parameterize "userType". How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

found my answer here [google-angular-discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/LrzcOQ1OnWg)

```
// our custom method is mapped as well.
  card.$charge({amount:9.99});
  // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
```

===============================================================================

PUT should have same behavior as POST in that the parameters you don't define with '@' (in this case 'amount' ) will be added as query params. If however, in your definition of the PUT resource you had {id: '@id', amount: '@amount' } then it would be passed along as JSON